# Find out which partition a directory is located on in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to find out which partition a directory is located in?

I know I can use `df` to list partitions and mount points but I need to be able to find out which partition any directory is located in with a simple command.

Comment: On UNIX with more answers: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-do-i-find-on-which-physical-device-a-folder-is-located

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
df -h .
```

gives you:

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2  1.4Ti  390Gi  1.0Ti    28%    /
```

so you have 'mounted on' for that dir

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/66492/in-nix-how-to-determine-which-filesystem-a-particular-file-is-on) post on serverfault. it should give you all the information you need.

Comment: It's recommended to copy the information to your post rather than referring to another page.

Answer (score 1):

```
[rajat@rajat ~]$ df -HT

Filesystem    Type     Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6     ext4      22G   7.4G    14G  36% /
tmpfs        tmpfs     1.1G   349k   1.1G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1     ext3     200M    53M   137M  28% /boot

[rajat@rajat ~]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6              20G  6.9G   13G  36% /
tmpfs                 987M  340K  986M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             190M   50M  131M  28% /boot

cd /dev/sda
```

Comment: Useful for me because shows type of FS